# Editing every value in a numpy matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, 2d

I have a numpy matrix which I filled with data from a *.csv-file

```
csv = np.genfromtxt (file,skiprows=22)
matrix = np.matrix(csv)
```

This is a 64x64 matrix which looks like

```
print matrix
[[...,...,....]
[...,...,.....]
.....
]]
```

Now I need to take the logarithm math.log10() of every single value and safe it into another 64x64 matrix.
How can I do this? I tried

```
matrix_lg = np.matrix(csv)
    for i in range (0,len(matrix)):
        for j in range (0,len(matrix[0])):
            matrix_lg[i,j]=math.log10(matrix[i,j])
```

but this only edited the first array (meaning the first row) of my initial matrix.
It's my first time working with python and I start getting confused.

Comment: did you try `np.log(np.matrix(csv))`?

Comment: Use matrix.shape to find out th nr of rows and cols. A numpy matrix isn't a list of lists. But of course Joran's solution is (much) faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do:

```
matrix_lg = numpy.log10(matrix)
```

And it will do it for you.  It's also much faster to do it this vectorized way instead of looping over every entry in python. It will also handle domain errors more gracefully.

FWIW though, the issue with your posted code is that the `len()` for matrices don't work exactly the same as they do for nested lists.  As suggested in the comments, you can just use `matrix.shape` to get the proper dims to iterate through:

```
matrix_lg = np.matrix(csv)
for i in range(0,matrix_lg.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0,matrix_lg.shape[1]):
        matrix_lg[i,j]=math.log10(matrix_lg[i,j])
```

Comment: why try it easy, when you can have it the hard way..

your solutions all worked fine. Thank you very much, people!